# Where is the composition root in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

I have found that I am using the DI container as a service locater in my Symfony2 controllers (i.e. getting a container reference to initialize objects in my actions). After checking out Mark Seemann's book where he clearly shows how you could compose objects in [ASP.NET MVC's controller factory](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx), I am wondering if there is a similar pattern in Symfony2?

Comment: Do you mean [controllers as services](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html)?

Comment: Yes and no. That is one way of doing it, however doesn't it require all dependencies to be registered before hand?

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is, is there opportunity there for me to explicity write code that says, for ABusinessController, I would need x, y, z, and maybe I am initializing z manually?

Comment: Yes it does. You define all services and define controllers as services too. Then you can inject only those services, that are needed by a controller instead of the whole container because it becomes just another service. Don't understand "initializing z manually". The container takes responsibility for creating and initializing service-objects. Anyway, that's the best you can get with symfony 2 ;)

Comment: Ah okay thanks. Yeah when I say "initializing z manually" I mean poor man's DI, if I am too lazy to wire up (and test the wiring) some 3rd party library, for example.